# Fortify Audit Workbench Scan Runner error

Tags: fortify

I am getting below error while running Fortify Audit Workbench.
Where can I see a full listing of the warnings and errors.

```
[error]: An error occurred while initializing the scan engine.

[warning]: Some errors or warnings were suppressed.  
Check the results file for a full listing of all warnings and errors.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used the AWB graphical user interface to try to run a scan.  There is no way to know what went wrong when you use that technique.

Instead, read the "SCA User Guide" document and run your translation and scan from the command line.

```
// clean
sourceanalyzer -b FOO -clean

// translate
sourceanalyzer -b FOO [your translation parameters]

// scan
sourceanalyzer -b FOO -scan -f FOO.fpr [your scan parameters]
```